# User input then split string

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have looked online for many solutions to my problem. I want to ask the user to input a sentence and write the sentence out one word per line using the split method. I have asked the user to enter a sentence and ran the console but the the sentence keeps appearing on the second line.

```
namespace Seperation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            string temp;
            string sentenceTwo = (" ");

            Console.WriteLine("please enter a sentence");
            temp = Console.ReadLine();
            sentenceTwo = temp;

            string[] split = sentenceTwo.Split(',');
            foreach (string item in split)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to split by space `" "`. right now you are splitting by comma `","`

Comment: @Nkosi I have already tried that but the sentence still appears as one instead of each word on separate lines

Comment: Can you provide a sample sentence you tried to split, yet failed?

Comment: Can you provide a sample sentence and expected result for that sentence.

Comment: I removed the comma from the Split and it worked @Nkosi

Comment: If the code now works, please do pick the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should split the string on space instead of on comma:

```
namespace Seperation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string temp;
            string sentenceTwo = (" ");

            Console.WriteLine("please enter a sentence");
            temp = Console.ReadLine();
            sentenceTwo = temp;

            string[] split = sentenceTwo.Split(' ');
            foreach (string item in split)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently splitting by a comma `,` only when you need to split by punctuations that may exist in a sentence like space `" "` comma `","` and peroid `"."`

```
//..other code
string[] split = sentenceTwo.Split(new char[]{' ', '.', ','}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string item in split)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
//..other code
```